# Find specific file type in a directory (C++)

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

I want to make a program that can search through a specific folder on my computer to find certain files. In this case I want it to look for text files. I've heard some sources claim that this can be done using the standard C++ library. If so, how can I go about doing this? I believe the working code should look something like this:

```
string path = "C:\\MyFolder\\";

while(/*Searching through the directory*/)
{
    if (/*File name ends with .txt*/)
    {
        /*Do something*/
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard c++ library does not provide a platform-independent way to browse files. You'll have to find examples for your current OS. EDIT: however, if you're looking for platform-independent wrapper classes, check out WxWidgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for working with directories in the standard library. There's however an effort to incorporate `Boost.Filesystem` into the C++17 standard. For now, you can just use `Boost` directly.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
  namespace ba = boost::algorithm;

  fs::path dir_path(".");

  for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(dir_path)) {
    if (fs::is_regular_file(entry)) {
      std::string path = entry.path().string();
      if (ba::ends_with(path, ".txt")) {
        // Do something with entry or just print the path
        std::cout << path << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**update:**

To compile the snippet, you need to have Boost installed (and compiled, Filesystem is not header-only). Follow the tutorials [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/index.html). Then make sure to link with `boost_filesystem`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cc -lboost_filesystem && ./a.out
```

And don't forget to create some `.txt` files in the same directory so that the program has something to chew on.

Comment: I downloaded Boost 1.57 in order to try this, but when including the two .hpp files it gives numerous errors such as "namespace boost has no member filesystem". Are there any more files or libraries that I need to include in order for the code to compile? If so, where can I find them?